# Replace avatar Url on Social login with Laravel Socialite

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-login, avatar

I'm facing an issue, I'm login with social networks and everything works perfect but my problem is with Avatars. When login, I get all the data including the Avatar but that avatar is saved in my database with Social Network original Url, I want to save it with my url instead.

In other words, I save the profile pictures using timestamps and original file extension in `Laravel`

This my provider callback method in controller

```
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request, $provider)
 {
     try
     {
         $socialUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
     }
     catch(\Exception $e)
     {
         return redirect('/');
     }
     //Check if we have logged on Social Provider

     $socialProvider =   SocialProvider::where('provider_id', $socialUser->getId())->first();
     if (!$socialProvider)
     {
         //Create a new user and provider
         $user = new User;
         $user->name = $socialUser->getName();
         $user->profilepic = $socialUser->getAvatar();
         $user->email = $socialUser->getEmail();

         if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
             $profilepic = $request->file('avatar');
             $filename = time() . '.' . $profilepic->getClientOriginalExtension();
             Image::make($profilepic)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );
             $user->profilepic = $filename;
         }

         $user->save();

         // $user = User::firstOrCreate([
         //   'name'  =>  $socialUser->getName(),
         //   'profilepic' => $socialUser->getAvatar(),
         //   'email' =>  $socialUser->getEmail()
         // ]);

         $user->socialProviders()->create(
           ['provider_id' => $socialUser->getId(), 'provider' => $provider]
         );

     Session::flash('success', 'Tu cuenta ha sido enlazada correctamente, sin embargo, ahora debes crear una contraseña. Crea tu contraseña ahora.');

    $user->save();
     auth()->login($user);

     return redirect('account-complete');

     }
     else
         $user = $socialProvider->user;

     auth()->login($user);

     return back();

 }
```

Im getting this URL with facebook:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/10155364486426042/picture?type=normal
```

This is how i want it to be

```
http://localhost:8000/uploads/avatars/1519702861.jpg
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
if ($socialUser->getAvatar()) {
    $filename = "uploads/avatar/".time().".jpg"; 
    // The filename to save in the database.
    file_put_contents(
        $filename, 
        file_get_contents($socialUsr->getAvatar())
    );
}
```

Above method will work given that the destination directory is writable by php.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I saved the "image" into the database "the name" but the problem was that image wasn't in my folder.. with this method i will get the image in the folder and the name in database right?

Comment: Yes. You can do exactly that. Look at the edited Answer. I've put some comments.